# Why do we ask you to use ```code``` blocks rather than screenshots?

Tags: discussion, faq

- `code` blocks are easier to read (we can give an example of `code` next to a screenshot if needed)
- `code` blocks are faster to load
- `code` blocks have text that is more "searchable".
- `code` blocks can even be read by screen readers for blind people (screenshots usually can't).
- `code` blocks can be seen on browsers that don't load images or have image blockers

Comment: They also take less space on the SE servers. It's also easier for the user!

Comment: IMO the biggest benefit is that it makes the code easy to copy/paste.

Comment: Technical: shouldn't the current body of this question be a (self-)answer, and the body instead be just elaborating on this generic FAQ?

Comment: @Neinstein sure, I can do that if there's a need :)